# A behavior when we parse non-number in arithmetic evaluation

Tags: bash

I know from the manpage from bash that the variable that is  null or unset is regarded as zero.
And I guess that non-number should be regarded as zero in arithmetic evaluation.
But without official ruling, it could be ambiguous like the second case of below example.

```
$ FOO=10
$ echo $((FOO))
10
$ FOO=10.abc
$ echo $((FOO))
bash: 10.abc: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".abc")
```

atoi() from C parses the second example as 10.
What's the formal semantic of 
parsing non-number in bash's arithmetic evaluation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$((` ... `))` construct for arithmetic expansion was first introduced in the Korn shell back in the '80s, and then adopted for bash (which originally had a different syntax for arithmetic expansions) and POSIX.

Bash and ksh93 expect well-formed arithmetic expressions inside `$(( ... ))`.  They go way beyond `atoi()` in parsing them.

How the shells handle empty and unset variables is a red herring in this case.  It's a sensible convenience that just happens to make sense in the context of the shell.

Comment: Not red herring imo. I think that the way shell handle empty/unset value, invalid value should be set well. I found the former case from manpage but still don't get the latter case.

Comment: In software you need to provide a correct answer, or bail out in order to stop any errors from propagating.